# How do I decode the following string in PHP?

Tags: php, string, decode

Does anyone know how to properly decode the following string in PHP?

```
=?iso-8859-1?Q?OLG=20Slots=20at=20Windsor=20=26=20Caesars=20Windsor=20w?=
```

I tried using

```
quoted_printable_decode()
```

but did not produce the desired result.

This string retrieved from an email header. This above string is the "Subject". It appears that email clients (both web-based and applications) are able to decode the string properly.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Doesn't looks encoded, how did you get this string?

Comment: What should it decode to? It looks like a query string, but if it is, then the `=20` would normally be `%20` - more clarification as to what should happen here, I think!

Comment: Show ***how*** you have tried it. Because that function ***does*** work on your input string.

Comment: @mario `quoted_printable_decode('=?iso-8859-1?Q?OLG=20Slots=20at=20Windsor=20=26=20Caesars=20Windsor=20w?=
');` does not work for me when I run it. I get the following output `=?iso-8859-1?Q?OLG Slots at Windsor & Caesars Windsor w?`, which is not correct.

Comment: Why the down-vote? This is a legitimate question.

Comment: Why is that not correct? It does transform the quoted printable encoding *as advertised*. It leaves the *non-standard* prefix alone. (Btw, don't write "had no effect" when you actually mean "but I get the following output").

Comment: @mario sorry, it didn't give me the required output. The accepted answer does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not url_encoded, instead try this :

```
$subject = '=?iso-8859-1?Q?OLG=20Slots=20at=20Windsor=20=26=20Caesars=20Windsor=20w?=';

echo utf8_decode(imap_utf8($subject));
```

[Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-utf8.php)

Comment: Excellent! That worked! I'll accept the answer once SO allows me to.

Answer (score 0):

The first bit suggests it's encoded in [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), which is, if I'm reading Wikipedia correctly, standard ASCII.

This means that you probably don't need to *decode* the string, you just need to *understand* it ;-)

Where did you find it? What do you think it's meaning might be? (eg is it submitted form data, some sort of RPC encoding, something else?)

Thank you! Just seen your edit. Have you tried b64 decoding it? At a guess it's [base64 encoded ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). Try [`base64_decode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php).

Comment: It is not base64 encoded, it is Q-encoded. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Difference_between_Q-encoding_and_quoted-printable